# Old javascript libraries with security vulnerabilities "hidden" by login?

Tags: javascript, security

Lets imagine a web application where you need to sign in to use all the features. So, if you do not have any account you can not use the application (you can not create an account on your own.)

Im looking at security issues. One part of it is to look at old javascript libraries used... But is it really necessary to upgrade them to get rid of the security vulnerabilities? The hackers need to sign in to exploit the javascript libraries?

Comment: "*The hackers need to sign in to exploit the javascript libraries?*" not necessarily. Let's assume that one of the libraries takes the query string from the URL and adds it as HTML. Then it's enough for a malicious user to merely send somebody a link with `yourapp.com/logged/in/area/?q=<script>alerty("XSS")</script>`. The victim then logs in and the attack is finished. That's just one of the more obvious examples, there are many other attacks that don't require a hacker to log in. And many others that will allow a hacker to login. And hackers *might already be legitimate users anyway*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the vulnerable JS is not served to non-logged in users at all. (And that is a pretty big assumption).

Attackers can launch attacks through legitimate users' browsers via techniques such as XSS, CSRF and social engineering. Legitimate users can go rogue or have their password fall into the hands of an attacker.

Patch your security holes. Don't assume bad actors can't get at them.

Comment: It's a common misconception that only security risks that go from "no access" to "full access" are a problem, but any tiny step in between those can be a problem. Even "almost full access" to "one tiny bit more" or "normal user access" to "normal user access, but can see who the administrators are". All of those can accumulate into a huge problem. Don't ignore what seems like a small issue.

Answer (score 1):

> So, if you do not have any account you can not use the application (you can not create an account on your own.)
>
> [...]
>
> The hackers need to sign in to exploit the javascript libraries?

Let me challenge your underlying assumption here. "Hackers" aren't some outside force. Let's call them by their proper name: *malicious users*. There are two fundamental issues here:

1. Nobody needs to have a user account to *use* your application. Having less privileges still means they use it *at best* at a lesser capacity.
2. People *with* a user account can be malicious.

These are, by far, the biggest problems with your assumption. Then *next* comes the issue that "outsiders" can still gain access you didn't intend for them through:

- privilege escalation - there was such an incident in back in May 2019. Happened on a site [called Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/25/a-deeper-dive-into-our-may-2019-security-incident/).
- social engineering - [the March 2011 breach of RSA Security](https://www.bankinfosecurity.com/tricked-rsa-worker-opened-backdoor-to-apt-attack-a-3504) was started via a social engineering attack.
- even stealing an account through unauthorised means - *the* biggest data breaches so far have been [Yahoo! data breaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_data_breaches). There is no accurate information of the full impact this would have had but it would have easily allowed attackers to impersonate a user on another service who registered with a Yahoo.com email.

So far, that's *just* about outsiders gaining more access to your system. Let's turn around and examine your users.

A disgruntled person who already has a user account can also act maliciously. This is not unheard of and it's a significant portion of the actual security incidents. Some case studies:

- [the July 2019 data breach of Capital One](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/07/29/business/capital-one-data-breach/index.html) was initiated by an employee from the inside.
- [the June 2018 data breach of Tesla](https://www.securityweek.com/tesla-breach-malicious-insider-revenge-or-whistleblowing) was similarly done by an employee.

Now, I don't actually know if you are better at security or have more resources to handle problems than the corporations like Stack Exchange, Yahoo!, or Tesla. Perhaps, it's still worth pointing out that [the Equifax data breach of March 2017](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3444488/equifax-data-breach-faq-what-happened-who-was-affected-what-was-the-impact.html) happened due to negligence. Due to a *massive* (in both cause and effect) failure on part of Equifax employees, a security hole in a framework used was not patched in time.